# Can I use ARFoundation instead of Vuforia? Does it support wide range of mobile phones?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Since ARFoundation is free, I'm thinking about using it on a project. What I need is only Image Tracking. But I have a few concerns:

1-) Vuforia supports almost any mobile phone with a camera. I remember, I was using it even in early 2014. If ARFoundation is mainly a framework which is a combination of ARCore and ARKit, I have concerns about it. I know ARKit supported on iPhone 6 Plus and later (fair enough), how about ARCore? Can I trust it on mid-tier Android phones released on late 2014 or more? Can someone define the trade off here?

2-) Implementing Vuforia on a Unity project is a piece of cake. I have a limited time. Would you bet on ARFoundation on a project? Is it "stable" enough or do I have to google it to work, like there's no tomorrow?

Edit: After a 6 months long project development, I have something to say: Use ARKit for IOS, and Vuforia for Android. This way, you will have less headache on Android and more power for AR in IOS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARCore is supported in a lot of devices but still exists a (really) big gap between the ones that works and don't work. 
You can check all supported devices here: https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

You can see that is missing really a lot of devices from before 2017-2018. 
Also, it's very important to know where do you plan to release your app, some countries probably have more users with the latest phones.

Lastly, Vuforia is really easy to add to a project, really really easy. 
ARFoundation is not really dificult, but it is not as easy as Vuforia, but it is stable, it's awesome. It's just a bit more complex to understand, but that is not really a problem, there are a lot of samples out there. You can start with the official ones: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples

If you want just marker based AR, stick to Vuforia. If you need more complex experiences using AR Planes it's better to use AR Foundation.

Comment: I checked the list. What I understand is its supported on many devices 2017+ right? Thanks btw

Comment: Yes, not all but I think that more companies started include ARCore to more of their devices by 2018. And the good news is that ARCore devices are being more accesible. Probably in a couple of years everyone will have an ARCore (or ARKit) supported device.
The adoption is really fast, people are always looking to buy new phones.